# Defining specific image size for Outlook-clients through CSS

Tags: html, css, email, litmus

I'm currently building a new HTML-template.

In one section I want to display a different image size for MS-Outlook, as it doesn't react in the same way as other clients.

Original:

```
<td align="left" class="column_one_half column_image" valign="top" width="100%">
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="" class="mso-size" src="https://xxx" width="100%"></a>
</td>
```

I need to show the image with the size width="270";height="190" in Outlook. I would like to use a CSS-declaration in the head.

I was trying the approach below, however it doesn't work. Litmus is showing no change. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and best,

---

This is what I tried:

The following structure works well, Litmus shows the expected result:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<td align="left" class="column_one_half column_image" valign="top" width="100%">
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="xxx" width="270" height="190"></a>
</td>
<div style="display:none">
<![endif]-->
                                                                        <td align="left" class="column_one_half column_image" valign="top" width="100%">
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="xxx" width="100%"></a>
</td>
                                                                        <!--[if mso]>
<div>
<![endif]-->
```

But, I don't want everyone to be forced to paste in the image-URL twice. I would like to use the CSS in the head instead.

I tried the following declaration (pasted it under the first -section:

```
   <!--[if mso]>  
    <style>
    img.mso-size {
    width:270px!important;
    height:190px!important;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Outlook on Windows use Word as a rendering engine. While they do support `width` and `height` in CSS, they do not for `<img>` elements. The only way to size an image is to use the HTML `width` attribute or VML as you showed.

Usually, what I do is declare the width I want in Outlook in the HTML attribute. And then in an inline style on the same image, apply styles I want for other clients. Based on your example, that could give:

```html
<img alt="" src="https://example.com" width="270" style="width:100%; max-width:270px;" />
```

Note that percentage values in the `width` attribute are also buggy in *The Outlooks* on Windows. (They’ll be based on the physical file size and not on the parent’s element size as you’d normally expect.) For more details on CSS support in email clients, you can refer to [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-width/).